# detecting a double tap in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to detect double tap in a uiwebview. following is the code. when i debug, debugger comes to initwithcoder but never to touchesbegan nor to selector function. why so ?

I am putting a UIWebView in my xib file and setting identity inspector class to MyWebView

```
#import "MyWebView.h"


@implementation MyWebView

- (void) initTap {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDoubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleFingerDoubleTap:)];
    singleFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    singleFingerDoubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDoubleTap];
    [singleFingerDoubleTap release];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        // Initialization code.
        [self initTap];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
        [self initTap];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)handleSingleFingerDoubleTap:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Doulble click detected !");
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
            //put you zooming action here
        NSLog(@"Doulble click detected !");
    }
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add delegate to the recognizer

```
singleFingerDoubleTap.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the following method to return YES.

```
#pragma mark Gesture recognizer delegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to add conform declaration to your class file.

Like this

```
@interface ORWebViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Answer (score -2):

In case, you want to override the default zooming action on double tap, [**this**](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/) will guide you.

**UPDATE:**

> Please do not consider above mentioned reference as the author has moved it.

You can find the references from [Disabling default zoom effect.](http://www.cnblogs.com/junz/archive/2010/08/18/1801951.html)

Comment: @onmyway133 - Thanks for informing as the post is too old and so possibly reference link may have deleted.

Comment: It would be appreciated if any of the negative raters have shared a working URL to help the other stockholder.!

Comment: An archived copy of the blog post referenced above may be found here: http://www.cnblogs.com/junz/archive/2010/08/18/1801951.html  — Thanks, alloc_iNit!